# 'Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected' error in code below

Tags: c#, object, mocking

I am getting the following error in the code below:

> Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

This code has to do with mock objects. Please do let me know how I should modify this code to remove this error. I tried removing the last brace, but it gave me even more errors. Also, when I try to build this code it says 'Build failed'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Test;

namespace Test
{
    namespace TestClass
    {
        namespace TestMethod
        {
                [TestClass]
                public class Test
                {
                    [Testmethod]

                    public void MyClass_GetTotal()
                    {
                       Moq.Mock<MyClass> myMockedClass = new Mock<MyClass>() { CallBase = true };

                    myMockedClass.Setup(x => x.GetTotal(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(1);
                    myMockedClass.Setup(x => x.GetTotal(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(2);

                    var actual = myMockedClass.Object.GetTotal(0, string.Empty);

                    Assert.AreEqual(2, actual);
                }
            }

        }
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main errors in the code structure that I can see immediately.  First, you definitely have an extra end brace }.  Secondly, you cannot have a line break separating your method decorator from your actual method.

```
[Testmethod]

public void MyClass_GetTotal()
```

needs to be

```
[Testmethod]
public void MyClass_getTotal()
```